# Calculated Field with formula DATEDIF

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, calculated-column, sharepoint-on-prem, calculated-column-formula

Im working with a calculated field and using a formula to retrieve the difference of the days between two dates, DATE1 and DATE2, my simple formula is:

```
=DATEDIF([DATE1], [DATE2],"d")
```

It works fine when DATE1 and DATE2 have value, but when DATE1 or DATE2 has no values I got the `#NÚM!` Error.

I searched about how to deal with errors in formulas on MSDN and find this useful topic:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx

So I make this formula:

```
=ISERROR(DATEDIF([DATE1] , [DATE2] ,"d"), "0", DATEDIF([DATE1] , [DATE2] ,"d"))
```

If the date difference between DATE1 and DATE2 brings me an error, I set the value of field to 0. If the difference brings me a number I set the value of the field with this number. But when I try to save this formula in the column, Sharepoint brings me te error "Could not save changes to the server" because he can't compile the formula.

I have 6 different fields in the list where I have to use DATEDIF function to return the difference of the days and a column to make the SUM of all date differences, when I get the #NÚM error I can't make this SUM.

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ISERROR()` takes only one parameter and returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`. It is typically used inside an `IF()` statement to evaluate a formula. What you probably want is something like

```
=if(ISERROR(DATEDIF([DATE1] , [DATE2] ,"d")),"0", DATEDIF([DATE1] , [DATE2] ,"d"))
```

In words: If the `DATEDIF` function returns an error, use "0", else use the result of the `DATEDIF` function.

Comment: It worked! And it was written on the msdn topic, I can't believe I didn't realize this. Thank you so much!

Comment: I think this is shorter: ``=IF( AND([DATE1],[DATE2]) , DATEDIF([DATE1],[DATE2]) , 0 )`` because empty dates are False values. And SP is loosly typed so "0" is equal to 0 (and *not confirmed*, "d" is the default value)

Comment: My focus was not on formula efficiency but on correcting the syntax so the error disappears. Your formula works wonderfully, of course, but uses a few shortcuts that novice users may be struggling with.