# Calculated Field with formula DATEDIF + dispay text

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have created a CustomList called BirthdayReminder and also set up a Site-workflow which runs everyday at 00:00 to update the fields - otherwise the Birthday Reminder will stay static.

> My aim is to check the nextBirthday if it's equal to todays date and
>   if so, display "Happy Birthday" - otherwise display the days remaining
>   including the text "has birthday in xx days"

Anyway, I got 2 fields and 2 calculated fields :

**Username | Birthday | nextBirthday | daysUntilNextBirthday**

nextBirthday:

```
=DATE(YEAR(Birthday)+DATEDIF(Birthday,TODAY(),"Y")+1,MONTH(Birthday),DAY(Birthday))
```

daysUntilNextBirthday:

```
=IF([nextBirthday]=TODAY(),"Happy Birthday","has birthday in "&DATEDIF(TODAY(),[nextBirthday],"d")&" days")
```

The custom list shows:

[image]


what I am worried about is that as soon as the Site-workflow runs, it will update both calculated fields. I wonder if the daysUntil... field will actually manage to display the "Happy BDay" before the nextBirthday gets updated! hmmm!!

I tried to somehow combine all this with the DATEIF but not much luck. 
This topic is similar to this:
[Calculated Field with formula DATEDIF](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/175462/calculated-field-with-formula-datedif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

Just in case someone else is after a solution and is a newbie like me lol 
This is what you need in the calculated field:

```
=IF((DATEDIF(TODAY(),B3,"d")= 365),"Happy Birthday","has birthday in "&(DATEDIF(TODAY(),B3,"d")&" days"))
```

Because, I have 2 x calculated fields and both are updated once the site-workflow has been run; the `daysUntilNextBirthday` uses the `nextBirthday` field to calculate the days - therefore it will always show 365 days when reaching the actual date of birth.

So, the formula above simply says if 365 say Happy Birthday otherwise "has birthday in xx days".

[image]

Hope this will be useful to somebody one day :D