# DATEDIF function returning wrong number of days

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, calculated-column, modern-experience, calculated-column-formula

I am not able to get the number of days between start and end dates.

I am using DATEDIF(Start_date,End_date,"D") which seems correct as per articles

https://support.office.com/en-US/client/results?Shownav=true&lcid=1033&ns=SPOStandard&version=16&omkt=en-US&ver=16&HelpId=WSSEndUser_FormulaSyntaxError

[Calculated Field with formula DATEDIF](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/175462/calculated-field-with-formula-datedif)

and I think I have set it up right but not able to figure out. Here is the picture, if you can spot what I am not seeing...thanks team.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select **Number** under **The data type returned from this formula is:** option in column settings.

**Reference**: [DATEDIF function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datedif-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c)

Comment: that's what it was. Thanks Ganesh